# c# Copy file (.exe) from network drive to local desktop

Tags: c#, file, copy

I'm trying to build a little "installer" for my program.

When the installer is started, it first check if all needed files exists. If yes it should copy two .exe files to the local desktop.

```
string pathBDE = @"Z:\FS4140\BDE-Tool\BDE2.0\SQL\BDE.exe";
string targetpath = @"C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/Desktop";
Console.WriteLine(targetpath);
File.Copy(pathBDE, targetpath);
```

The error i get: System.IO.IOException: "The file 'C:\Users\z0047shw\Desktop' already exists."

I've also tried it with this targetpath as i saw it in some youtube videos, but still not working. : `string targetpath = @"C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/Desktop/BDE.exe";`
But here i get following error:

System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\z0047shw\Desktop\BDE.exe'."

I would need also that if the file in the targetpath is already existing, that it should be overwritten, dont know if that is working with File.Copy

Comment: File.Copy documentation clearly indicates such exception if the dest file exists. In such case, you must use File.Delete before copy.

Comment: as Windows pathes might not always be as they appear (ex. when your "Desktop" is stored in OneDrive), you could try it with saver path. Maybe create a folder c:\test and copy the file there. If that works, maybe check location of your Desktop-folder.
If you create a path from different strings, you should consider using Path.Combine(String, String) to build a proper path.

Answer (score 0):

What your code is trying to do is copy the .exe to the `/Desktop` directory. If you want to copy the exe you should tell it what *file* to copy to. the `/Desktop` would become `/Desktop/filename.exe` then.
The `File.Copy` method tries to move a copy of the original file to the destination *file*, not the destination *directory*, so you should specify a file name.

The following code should work better:

```cs
string pathBDE = @"Z:\FS4140\BDE-Tool\BDE2.0\SQL\BDE.exe";
// specify file name in this line -----------------------------------v
string targetpath = @"C:/Users/" + Environment.UserName + "/Desktop/BDE.exe";
Console.WriteLine(targetpath);
File.Copy(pathBDE, targetpath);
```

For the users desktop directory, it would be better to use `Environment.GetFolderPath()`. Then the line with `string targetpath` would become

```cs
string targetpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory)
 + "/BDE.exe";
```

the `C:\Users\username\Desktop` folder might not exist as some of the folders in there are virtual. The `Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory` points to the actual directory.

Comment: What do u mean with the comment line: specify file name in this line?
When i run this code what i tried already i got this error:
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\z0047shw\Desktop\BDE.exe'."

Comment: @Code123 that means a parent directory does not exist.  That could mean the original path is incorrect or the new path is incorrect, or you don't have access to the folder

Comment: it's a problem with OneDrive i suppose